# Hex assembly editor command primer?

Tags: compiler-construction, hex, disassembly

I am playing around with reverse engineering software. I have basic coding experience but only with top level languages like java and python.

I have dissassembled some exe's with IDA pro to poke around at the flow structure and am using Hex Workshop to edit the hex code and recompile. So, I have all those mechanics down and can create my edited exe successfully.

Are there any good guides for what the commands are and how they work? I could not find anything with my google-fu. I am not even sure what they are called. It is so different than the coding I am used to that I am really struggling with parsing it in my head.

I am talking about jz, jnz, eax, lea, mov, cmp and so forth. I can find some scattered references to individual commands that are somewhat helpful, but not enough to do useful things with. I am looking for a good primer on the whole subject. Something I can plow through and come out with a basic understanding of what they do and how to change them to do what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for "assembly language"  guides, specifically for x86 or x86-64. Reinhart's answer has a link to the reference material, but you may want to read a tutorial before using it.

Answer (score 1):

`jz`, `mov`, etc... Those are called *instructions*, not commands (except for `eax`, which is a *register*).

The bytes you are editing are called *opcodes*, and those are what the processor fetches from memory and decodes into instructions.

Example:  When you see

```
.text:00428E4A  8B F0    mov   esi, eax
```

The correct way to describe this line would be:   At address 0x00428E4A are the opcodes 8B F0.  Those opcodes are decoded to the `mov` instruction, with source operand being the `eax` register, and destination operand being the `esi` register.

The definitive source of nitty-gritty information here is the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).  Specifically, you want Volume 2, the Instruction Set Reference, A-Z.

Comment: I'm always surprised that people don't know about the Intel manuals. If you're going to be doing (x86) binary analysis, these are crucial! One small note: when looking at binary code (i.e. disassembling, as opposed to assembling) be sure to reference "Appendix A: Opcode Map" in Volume 2 of the Intel manuals (currently in the Vol-2b PDF). While Vol 2 lets you look up asm instructions by mnemonic, the Opcode Map lets you look up instructions by opcode (byte encodings).

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the CPU for which the EXE was compiled. Then you google for the assembly language of this CPU. In the unlikely case you do not find it you search for the datasheets of the CPU.